# insert element with element tree to existing xml

Tags: python, xml, string, elementtree

I'm trying to find the simplest way to add an element to these item entries using element tree.

I have the below XML output stored in (xmldata). I don't want to write this to a file yet, I just need to add the id so I an further use the data by relating it to a corresponding id in other data.

Where you see

```
     <archived type="bool">False</archived>
```

Just above that I want to add

```
     <id>555666</id>
```

to all items in the list (same id to all)

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
            <root>
                <tasks type="list">
                    <item type="dict">
                        <archived type="bool">False</archived>
                        <budget_spent type="float">0.0</budget_spent>
                        <billable_hours type="float">0.0</billable_hours>
                        <billable type="bool">True</billable>
                        <billable_amount type="float">0.0</billable_amount>
                        <budget_left type="null"/>
                        <over_budget_percentage type="null"/>
                        <task_id type="int">6356</task_id>
                        <detailed_report_url type="str">/reports/detailed/</detailed_report_url>
                        <name type="str">Planning</name>
                        <internal_cost type="float">0.0</internal_cost>
                        <budget type="null"/>
                        <budget_spent_percentage type="null"/>
                        <total_hours type="float">0.0</total_hours>
                        <over_budget type="null"/>
                        <billed_rate type="float">0.0</billed_rate>
                    </item>
                    <item type="dict">
                        <archived type="bool">False</archived>
                        <budget_spent type="float">0.0</budget_spent>
                        <billable_hours type="float">0.0</billable_hours>
                        <billable type="bool">True</billable>
                        <billable_amount type="float">0.0</billable_amount>
                        <budget_left type="null"/>
                        <over_budget_percentage type="null"/>
                        <task_id type="int">6357</task_id>
                        <detailed_report_url type="str">/detailed/123</detailed_report_url>
                        <name type="str">Planning</name>
                        <internal_cost type="float">0.0</internal_cost>
                        <budget type="null"/>
                        <budget_spent_percentage type="null"/>
                        <total_hours type="float">0.0</total_hours>
                        <over_budget type="null"/>
                        <billed_rate type="float">0.0</billed_rate>
                    </item>
                </tasks>
```

**** update ****

Based on the answer from DAXaholic I've added this:

```
     tree = ET.fromstring(xmldata)
     for item in tree.iterfind('tasks/item'):
      idtag = ET.Element('id')
      idtag.text = '555666'
      item.insert(0, idtag)
```

not sure how to finish this off so I have the updated data to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should give you the idea

```
root = ET.fromstring(xmldata)
for item in root.iterfind('tasks/item'):
    idtag = ET.Element('id')
    idtag.text = '555666'
    item.insert(0, idtag)
xmldata = ET.tostring(root, encoding="unicode")
```

Comment: I think that might work... one thing. I'm not using a file... I'm using a varaible, so instead of ET.parse('filename') I'm doing tree = ET.fromstring(xmldata). how would I "write" the changes back to (xmldata) because this won't work if im not using a file tree.write('modified.xml')

Comment: Ah sry - misread your comment. You can use https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring for that

Comment: I will adjust my answer once I am back - currently AFK

Comment: I'm trying to read the documentation but I dont really understand how tostring works. I keep getting a bytes error, but I think its because I'm not using it right.  I'll update my question with what I have based off your reply.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you. I actually tried that last line, but I used encoding="us-ascii" as per the documentation. Maybe that explains my error. Thanks again for your time. Learning this stuff is very cool and helpful.