# How to include OSIS tag <title> to existing python osis2usfm.py script

Tags: python, xml

From page https://github.com/raamattu/osis2usfm I got a python script.
This script converts OSIS XML file structure from one file to USFM TEX structure in separate files.

I already improved script with some lines (added: h1, toc1, toc3, mt1). This was not hard.

Then, with my knowledge of `sed` I already manage to manually add book title to each python generated `.usfm` file, but then I got to the Psalms where I would have to do even bigger workarounds to capture also Psalm titles (replacements within three lines of text).

So I tried to put `<title>` tags in `osis2usfm.py`, but phyton is too complicated for me. Whatever I tried python give me errors, specially with spaces.

I would like to ask if somebody can help me to add these two tags  `<title type="main">  .. main to be included..  </title>` and `<title type="chapter">  ..chapter to be included..  </title>` in `osis2usfm.py` to capture some additional text from my `osis.xml` example where I added their position.

I do not use additional file `booknames.txt` so this part of code can be omitted.

=====UPDATED QUESTION:=====

- Thanks for your quick answer. It gives me the resulted two files: `test_01_GEN.usfm` and `test_02_EXO.usfm`
- Text `..chapter12 to be included..` now goes to the result file. That is super, but not on right place.
  So I figure out, that my question was not very well formed. I didn't tell how resulted file should look like. I think some changes should also be done on lover part of python script to include `\mt1` and `\d`.

Result is now: `test_01_GEN.usfm`

```
\id GEN
\h  
\h1 
\toc1 
\toc2 
\toc3 
\mt1 
\c 1
\p 
\c 2
\v 1   ..chapter12 to be included..  \v 2  book1 line 1
```

Desired result should be: `test_01_GEN.usfm`

```
\id GEN
\h 
\h1
\toc1
\toc2
\toc3
\mt1   ..main11 to be included..  
\c 1  
\p
\d   ..chapter12 to be included..  
\v 1  book1 line 1
```

=====

*osis.xml  (UPDATED <title tag with numbers and added text in first line)

```
  <osis>
      <osisText>
        <header>
          ... this is ignored ...
        </header>
        <div type="x-testament">
          <div type="book"><title type="main">  ..main11 to be included..  </title>
            <chapter><title type="chapter">  ..chapter12 to be included..  </title>
              <verse> book1 line 1
              </verse>
            </chapter>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div type="x-testament">
          <div type="book"><title type="main">  ..main21 to be included..  </title>
            <chapter><title type="chapter">  ..chapter22 to be included..  </title>
              <verse> book2 line 1
              </verse>
            </chapter>
          </div>
        </div>
      </osisText>
    </osis>
```

osis2usfm.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# osis2usfm.py
# OSIS to USFM transformation script.
#
# Copyright (C) 2012 Jaakko Luttinen
#
# This file is licensed under Version 3.0 of the GNU General Public
# License.

"""
Python script for transforming Bible in OSIS format to USFM format.
The script transforms OSIS Bible to USFM Bible. It is assumed that the
XML structure of the OSIS file is:

    <osis>
      <osisText>
        <header>
          ... this is ignored ...
        </header>
        <div type="x-testament">
          <div type="book">
            <chapter>
              <verse>
              </verse>
              ...
            </chapter>
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
        <div type="x-testament">
          <div type="book">
            <chapter>
              <verse>
              </verse>
              ...
            </chapter>
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
      </osisText>
    </osis>

No other tags are understood, thus it is a very simple transformation.

Usage:

    python osis2usfm.py inputfile.osis

Outputs a set of files named inputfile_##_XXX.usfm where ## is the
number of the book and XXX is the id of the book.

It is also possible to give the names of the books as a separate text
file. This file should have syntax:

    GEN=Genesis
    EXO=Exodus
    ...
    XXX=Whatever name you want to give to the book
    ...

where XXX is the ID of the book.  Usage:

    python osis2usfm.py inputfile.osis booknames.txt

"""

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import codecs
import sys
from os.path import splitext

filename = sys.argv[1]
basename = splitext(filename)[0]

# Parse XML
tree = ET.parse(filename)

root = tree.getroot()

# Book IDs
ids = (
    'GEN',
    'EXO',    # Excluded 62 books -> code to be shorter
    'JUD',
    'REV',
)

# Use booknames if given
booknames = {}
if len(sys.argv) >= 3:
    # namefile = open(sys.argv[2])
    namefile = codecs.open(sys.argv[2],
                           mode='r',
                           encoding='utf-8')
    while True:
        line = namefile.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        pass  # do something    while
        (id, name) = line.split("=")
        booknames[id] = unicode.strip(name)
    namefile.close()

id_ind = 0
for testament in root[0][1:]:
    for (book_ind, book) in enumerate(testament):
        # Write each book in a separate file
        outfile = basename + ('_%02d_' % (id_ind+1)) + ids[id_ind] + '.usfm'
        f = codecs.open(outfile,
                        mode='w',
                        encoding='utf-8')

        f.write(u"\\id " + ids[id_ind] + "\n")
        if ids[id_ind] in booknames and booknames[ids[id_ind]]:
            f.write(u"\\h  " + booknames[ids[id_ind]] + u"\n")
            f.write(u"\\toc2 " + booknames[ids[id_ind]] + u"\n")
        else:
            f.write(u"\\h  \n")
            f.write(u"\\h1 \n")
            f.write(u"\\toc1 \n")
            f.write(u"\\toc2 \n")
            f.write(u"\\toc3 \n")
            f.write(u"\\mt1 \n")
        for (chapter_ind, chapter) in enumerate(book):
            f.write(u"\\c %d\n" % (chapter_ind+1))
            if chapter_ind == 0:
                f.write(u"\\p \n")
            for (verse_ind, verse) in enumerate(chapter):
                f.write(u"\\v %d " % (verse_ind+1))
                if verse.text:
                    f.write(verse.text)
                #  f.write(u"\n")
        id_ind += 1

        f.close()
```

Comment: It would be better to [add elements to xml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38993280/2834978) before converting

Answer (score 0):

Adding `title` elements where needed before converting

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
>>> root = tree.getroot()
>>> for item in tree.getroot().iterfind('.//div[@type="book"]'):
...      t = ET.Element('title')
...      t.set("type", "main")
...      t.text = '..main to be included..'
...      t.tail = item.tail
...      item.insert(0,t)
...      ch = item.find("chapter")
...      t2 = ET.Element('title')
...      t2.set("type", "chapter")
...      t2.text = '.. chapter ..'
...      t2.tail = ch.tail
...      ch.insert(0, t2)
```